# Is the Term "Hafiz e Quran" jaiz?

Tags: shirk, asma-ul-husna, terminology

We often use the term "Hafiz e Quran" for the people who have memorized it. But as far I know, Al-Hafiz is one of the attribute of Allah. So it seems like shirk to use this term for a person who memorizes it. Can anyone please let me know…

- …is it a jaiz term to use for people who memorizes Quran?
- …which term did come in Quran and Hadith for the people who memorized Quran?
- …here does this term "Hafiz e Quran" for the people who memorize it come from?

Please give answer with the reference from Quran and Hadith with the reference number so that I can cross check.

Comment: Hafiz is not in the 99 names of Allah (swt)!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is jaiz to say "hafith al Quraan". It is rather a language matter that will make it right or wrong, as the word hafith (حافظ) can be used in two contexts in arabic.

The first context in which hafith is used in, is when you mean preservation, like in (حافظ أحمد على الكتاب) which means, Ahmed preserved the book, and prevented it from harm. If this context is meant when saying hafith al Quraan, then it may be wrong.

The second context is when you mean memorise, such as in (حفظ أحمد القرآن), which means, Ahmed memorised the Quraan, حفظ here is the verb, but when you say حافظ (hafith) it is the noun, meaning memorizer, so we can say ( أحمد حافظ للقرآن), which means Ahmed is a memorizer of the Quraan. In this case, it is totally fine to say so.

**Please do correct me if anything is wrong.**

Comment: can you please quote a Sahih Hadith which use the term Hafiz e Quran? We always have a say about something. We even do not need a qualification to talk about Islam. About Islam we should not jump into conclusion this first.

Comment: مثل الذي يقرأ القرآن ، وهوحافظ له ، مع السفرة الكرام البررة ، ومثل الذي يقرأ القرآن، وهو يتعاهده ، وهو عليه شديد ، فله أجران

الراوي : عائشة أم المؤمنين | المحدث :البخاري | المصدر : صحيح البخاري

Comment: It doesn't exactly say hafith al quraan, but hafith lahu.

Comment: what does "hafith lahu" means?

Comment: Lahu cannot be literally translated to english, but it has the meaning of " of it", so it will be "a memorizer of it".

Comment: Is there any Sahih Hadith which directly says that the person who hifazat quran get this prize, or something like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30664/discussion-between-ahmmad-ismail-and-abdel-rahman-shamel).